# Threejs Cloning meshes animation

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

I'm making copies of a 3d json model which i've animated, and it works if I only have 1 model in the scene.

But when I'm trying to make some copies, it appears the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

The following function is where the error is referencing to:

```
for(i =0; i < enemics_generats; i++ ){

    var enemic = dolent.clone(true); //Clone from original model
    enemic.name = i.toString();
    if (i > 5){//set 5 visible, the rest invisble
        enemic.visible = false;
    }
    else{
        enemic.visible = true; 
    } 

    enemic.box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(enemic);//Box collider
    enemic.box_helper = new THREE.BoxHelper( enemic ); //Box to be displayed on the scene

    //ERROR IS ON THIS 2 FOLLOWING LANES

    enemic.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( enemic );
    enemic.mixer.clipAction( enemic.animations[ 0 ] ).play(); //HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR APPEARS

    enemics.push(enemic);//Add to the array

    scene.add(enemic);//Add to scene
    scene.add(enemic.box_helper);
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Where your animations property or function is defined.

Comment: The JSON loader reads the animations from the file,  and stores them in the animations property.

Comment: So, "dolent" (which is the original loaded model), has the animation inside.

Comment: you can output the enemic to see if it has animations

Comment: I've found a parcial solution, I just play the "Dolent animation" which should be the same for all his copies.

Answer (score 0):

`Object3D.clone` will not copy your animations array. It will only copy properties pertinent to the THREE.js object. You will need to manually copy (or reference) your animations array in your cloned object.

```js
var obj1 = new THREE.Object3D();
obj1.someProperty = "test";
var obj2 = obj1.clone();
console.log(obj2.someProperty); // undefined
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
```

Comment: Good to know, I will make a reference to the original animation. 

Thanks